# Sending events to the dev version of a ruleset via HTTP

Tags: krl

I've been writing an endpoint that sends events to a KRL ruleset via HTTP GET (based on the [documentation here](http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/KNS_Event_API_Documentation#Event_Signaling)), in this format:

```
http://cs.kobj.net/blue/event/{domain}/{eventname}/{appid}
```

That works great when the version of the app I want to test is the same one that's deployed. I don't always want to deploy before testing it, though. Using the stated format for calling the dev version doesn't work. It still calls the deployed version of my ruleset:

```
http://cs.kobj.net/blue/event/{domain}/{eventname}/{appid}:kynetx_app_version=dev
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{appid}:kynetx_app_version=dev
```

is a query parameter so it needs to come after a '?' or a '&'

Changing your query to the following should get it to work

```
http://cs.kobj.net/blue/event/{domain}/{eventname}/{appid}/?{appid}:kynetx_app_version=dev
```

Comment: Actually you need to have the {appid} in the URL as well, before the query param. Like this: http://cs.kobj.net/blue/event/{domain}/{eventname}/{appid}/?{appid}:kynetx_app_version=dev  You might want to fix that, Mike.